# Last occurence of a cell in excel sheet based on 2 conditions

Tags: excel-formula

```
id    request   count

23415   ABC      1    
23415   XYZ      1    
54167   ABC      1    
33405   ABC      1    
23415   XYZ      2    
23415   XYZ      3    
12346   ABC      1    
23415   ABC      2
```

On each new entry I need to check if it is present previously along with the request type and update it according to its last occurrence. In the example above, if I try to add 1 more entry for 23415, then based upon the request type (`ABC` or `XYZ`), I need to update the count.

I already know how to increase count with last occurrence of just 23415 with the formula `=IFERROR(IF(E2=VLOOKUP(E2,$E1:E$2,1,0),SUM(INDEX($G1:$G$2,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($E1:$E$2)*($E2=$E1:$E$2))-1)),1),1),1)`, where E is id, F is request, and G is count.

However, I need to combine another condition with it for request type, i.e. last occurrence of 23415 if request is `ABC` then count should be 3 else if its `XYZ`, it should be 4. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS($E$2:E2,E2,$F$2:F2,F2)
```

Put in G2 and copy down.

Pay attention to what is and what is not an absolute reference.  This is always looking at the range from the line in which the formula is placed and up.

[image]

Comment: @BhishmNarula if this worked for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.